# Why is this Galois group abelian?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Consider the field extension $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_8)/\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$, with intermediate fields $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3,\zeta_8)$.

Denote

> $L:=\mathbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_8)$, $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$, $M_1=\mathbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]2)$, $M_2=\mathbb Q(\zeta_3,\zeta_8)$

Now I know that the extension $L/K$ is galois. I think that all other subextensions are galois too (?)

How do I see from this, that the Galois group of $L/K$ is abelian?

Comment: I assume that $\zeta_8$ is an eighth-root of 1 but which one?

Comment: How do you know that those are the only intermediate fields? The ones you have listed are all Galois over $K$ since they are all splitting fields. I would calculate the order of the Galois group. Note that the finite nonabelian groups that have all subgroups normal must have order divisible by $8$.

Comment: I'm not sure what your'e looking for here, exactly.  It's not true that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the only intermediate fields -- there's also $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,i)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,i\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,i\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[6]{2})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,i\sqrt[6]{2})$.  Do you just want to know what the Galois group is?

Comment: I didn't mean to claim that they are the only ones. I just think that the intermediate fields help to split the Galois group into two parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic facts about [linearly disjoint extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_disjoint) and how they mesh with extensions being Galois give you everything you want. If you have not seen the concept before you can use [the notes I prepared for a local seminar](https://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf) as a first aid. Pete L. Clark has published more extensive and polished lecture notes on [his web page](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf).

Anyway:

1. $M_1/K$ is a Galois extension and cyclic of degree three because it is a root extension of the type, where the base field contains the appropriate roots of unity.
2. $M_2/K$ is a Galois extension, of degree four with the Galois group isomorphic to the Klein four group. This is because $M_2$ is the 24th cyclotomic field.
3. Because $[M_1:K]=3$ and $[M_2:K]=4$ are coprime we have $M_1\cap M_2=K$.
4. For two Galois extensions (of the same field $K$) the trivial intersection condition of item 3 is equivalent to the extensions being linearly disjoint, so (see Proposition 7 in my notes) the compositum $L=M_1M_2$ is Galois over $K$, and the Galois group
   $$
   Gal(L/K)\cong Gal(M_1/K)\times Gal(M_2/K)
   $$
   is thus abelian as a direct product of two abelian groups.

---

The relevant results can surely also be found in many textbooks:

- Two Galois extensions are linearly disjoint, iff their intersection is trivial.
- The compositum of two linearly disjoint Galois extensions is itself Galois, and the corresponding Galois group is the direct product of the Galois groups of the two smaller extensions.

Comment: One answer-lesson that I liked

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think this is so hard. Your ground field is $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$, the field of cube roots of unity. You have one extension gotten by adjoining to $K$ the cube root of $2$, and this is abelian, in fact cyclic of order $3$. The other extension of $K$ is gotten by adjoining the eighth roots of unity, and that’s abelian, since it’s already abelian over $\Bbb Q$. So you have a compositum of two abelian extensions of $K$, and this extension is consequently abelian.